# Populating a generator. Is it possible?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode

I have a generator that generates a circle(SKShapeNode) every 2 seconds from the y-axis. (Moves up). I would like to know if it is possible to populate this generator uniformly(every x number of points.

Here is my code for said generator:

```
class CircleGen: SKShapeNode {
    var circles = [WhiteCircles]()
    var circleTracker = [WhiteCircles]()
    var generationTimer: NSTimer!
    var circ: WhiteCircles!

    func generateCircles() {
        for var i = 0; i < 4; i++ {
            var scale: CGFloat
            let rand = arc4random_uniform(10)
            if rand == 0 {
                scale = -15.0
            } else {
                scale = 15.0
            }
            let circle = WhiteCircles()
            circle.position.x = lineGen.position.x

            circle.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            circle.position.y = 35
            self.circles.append(circle)
            circleTracker.append(circle)
            foregroundNode.addChild(circle)
        }
    }

    func startGeneratingEvery(seconds: NSTimeInterval) {
        let callGenerateAction = SKAction.runBlock { () -> Void in
            self.generateCircles()
        }
        let waitOneSecond = SKAction.waitForDuration(seconds)

        let sequenceAction = SKAction.sequence([callGenerateAction, waitOneSecond])

        let circleGenerateAction = SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequenceAction)
        self.runAction(circleGenerateAction, withKey: "generateCircles")
    }
}
```

Will post more code if necessary. Thank you in advance.

Comment: so you are trying to create a circle everytime the previous circle reaches a specific place on the y axis?

Comment: No. I am doing exactly what you said, but in different places in my scene. Like having a line of circles moving up, but taking that line and copying it however many times in different positions.